# return a numpy array using multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

i have the following function,

```
def detect_face(image, return_val):
 frame = Image.open('input/' + image + '.jpg')
 face_boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(np.array(frame), model='cnn')

 if len(face_boxes) > 1:
    print("-----2 faces detected in {} image-----".format(image))
    return_val.append(None)
    return

 elif len(face_boxes) == 0:
    print("-----No face detected in {} image-----".format(image))
    return_val.append(None)
    return

 top, right, bottom, left = np.squeeze(face_boxes)
 frameCropped = frame.crop(box=(left, top, right, bottom + 15))

 frame_resized = np.array(frameCropped.resize((224, 224)))
 Image.fromarray(frame_resized).save('input/cropped_' + image + '.jpg')

 preprocess_image = np.expand_dims(np.array(frame_resized, dtype=np.float64), 0)
 preprocess_image = preprocess_input(np.array(preprocess_image), version=1)

 fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(5,12))
 ax[0].imshow(np.array(frame))
 ax[0].axis('off')
 ax[1].imshow(np.array(frame_resized))
 ax[1].axis('off')
 ax[2].imshow(np.array(preprocess_image[0]))
 ax[2].axis('off')

 return_val.append(preprocess_image)
 return preprocess_image

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_val = manager.list()

preprocess_image = Process(target=detect_face, args=('ammar', return_val))
preprocess_image.start()
preprocess_image.join()

print(return_val)
```

the return_val is always an empty list
how to return my numpy array using multiprocessing module
i have tried to search for the answer but it seems i am doing something wrong

Comment: Your function returns explicitly *nothing*, and your code does not receive anything from it either. Why would you expect there to be a return value? Are you aware that passing a list to a process, as with the ``return_val`` parameter/argument, only sends a copy whose changes are not reflected in the original?

Comment: i have edited my code to return preprocess_image as i want the numpy array to be returned from my function @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

n_elements = 1000 # how many elements your numpy should have

def myProc( shared_var ):
    '''
    here you convert your shared variable from mp.RawArray to numpy
    then treat it as it is numpy array e.g. fill it in with some 
    random numbers for demonstration purpose
    '''
    var = np.reshape( np.frombuffer( shared_var, dtype=np.uint32 ), -1 )
    for i in range( n_elements ):    
        var[i] = np.random.randint( 0, 2**16, 1 )
    print( 'myProc var.mean() = ', var.mean() )               
                                  
#buffer that contains the memory
mp_var = mp.RawArray( 'i', n_elements )
p = mp.Process( target=myProc, args=(mp_var,) )
p.start()                                      
p.join()
#after the process has ended, you convert the buffer that was passed to it
var = np.reshape( np.frombuffer( mp_var, dtype=np.uint32 ), -1)
#and again, you can treat it like a numpy array
print( '   out var.mean() = ',var.mean() )
```

Comment: i have (1, 224, 224, 3) array shape could you please advise